# Laravel manualy link storage

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am aware of

```
php artisan storage:link
```

that it is the laravel way of symlink(),
But when i uploaded my laravel project to a cpanel that i can use a command or SSH. I am wondering how i will implement this manually also i have try adding this line of code.

```
App::make('files')->link(storage_path('app/public'), public_path('storage'));
```

to AppServiceProvider and i use App. But it generate error. Is there any way around this.

Comment: Did you try to use cron and run command?

Comment: I am not aware of running command with cron. I think cron is use for running schedule job

Comment: yes, you put for example every minute or every 5 minute cron job. Once it is done you can check is symlink created and remove cron.

Comment: @Sakezzz. I have try implementing the cron job but it does not work also. Is there not a way in laravel settings file or any file to add code to resolve this issue.

Comment: what was cron error? In cpanel as I know you could look the result of error.